# Writing an array to a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written some script that reads an array (of Responses - multiple rows and columns) from a spreadsheet sheet, extracts data from each row into one or two lines (Entries) which are pushed into a 'main' array, and then writes that 'main' array to a different sheet. Each row of the Responses can contain one or two Entries - shown by a marker value.

Works well except that only the last Entry is pasted, the correct number of rows, to the second sheet.

Somewhere I am not placing the value of each object into the Entry array, just a reference to the value, but cannot see where I have gone wrong.

The spreadsheet is at 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x-HO7KIAQ_s7q55opTd2LRpRRo95S1CqeH193RalWS0/pubhtml

and my script is as follows:

```
function transferResponses() {
// establish sheets
  var aFile = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var aResponseSh = aFile.getSheetByName("Form responses 1");
  var aBaseSh = aFile.getSheetByName("Base");

// check number of response
  var numResponses = aResponseSh.getLastRow() - 1;
// put responses in an array
  var aResponses = aResponseSh.getSheetValues(2, 1, numResponses, 23);

// define other variables to use
  var oneEntry = [];      // array for a single entry
  var aEntries = [];      // array of all entries
  var aNumber;            // increment part of ID

// counters, etc
  var iRes;
  var iCol;
  var iEntry = 0;

  for (iRes = 0; iRes < numResponses; iRes++) {    
    aNumber = iEntry + 101;
    oneEntry[0] = "A" + aNumber.toString();        // form and load entry ID
    for (iCol = 1; iCol < 12; iCol++) {            // load name, surname, address 1, address 2,     phone, email
      oneEntry[iCol] = aResponses[iRes][iCol];     //   and first entry title, classification,     size, description, price
    }
    oneEntry[12] = aResponses[iRes][18];           // load novice status
    oneEntry[13] = aResponses[iRes][21];           // load date of entry
    oneEntry[14] = aResponses[iRes][22];           // load method of payment

    aEntries.push(oneEntry.valueOf());             // push entry (oneEntry) into main aray     (aEntries)

    iEntry = iEntry + 1;                           // increment single entry counter

    if (aResponses[iRes][12] === "Add another entry") {     // check for a second entry on     response
      aNumber = iEntry + 101;
      oneEntry[0] = "A" + aNumber.toString();        // form and load entry ID
      for (iCol = 1; iCol < 7; iCol++) {             // load name, surname, address 1, address 2,     phone, email
        oneEntry[iCol] = aResponses[iRes][iCol];     //   and first entry title, classification,     size, description, price
      }
      for (iCol = 7; iCol < 12; iCol++) {            //   and second entry title, classification,     size, description, price
        oneEntry[iCol] = aResponses[iRes][iCol + 6];
      }
      oneEntry[12] = aResponses[iRes][18];           // load novice status
      oneEntry[13] = aResponses[iRes][21];           // load date of entry
      oneEntry[14] = aResponses[iRes][22];           // load method of payment

      aEntries.push(oneEntry.valueOf());             // push entry (oneEntry) into main aray     (aEntries)

      iEntry = iEntry + 1;                           // increment single entry counter
    }
  } 

  lastRow = aBaseSh.getLastRow();
  if (lastRow > 1) {                             // clear all existing data on base sheet
    aBaseSh.deleteRows(2, lastRow);
  }

  aBaseSh.getRange(2, 1, aEntries.length, aEntries[0].length).setValues(aEntries);    // paste     main array (aEntries)

}
```

Comment: Try changing the loop values to :  for (iRes = 0; iRes <= numResponses; iRes++)

Comment: Thanks KRR, but that just tries to read past the end of the array aResponses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in every Array after each the equals:

```
oneEntry[iCol] = aResponses[iRes][iCol].slice(0);
```

or if only one string:

```
oneEntry[iCol] = aResponses[iRes][iCol].valueOf;
```

Also, you question is not specific, *Writing an array to a spreadsheet* is a pretty generic one, and has nothing to do with your error, wich is caused by Array *referencing* instead of *cloning*, your question should also be minimized while still reproducing the error.

Comment: Kriggs, thanks for your comment - "referencing instead of cloning" allowed me to sort things out. The error lay in using .valueOf() instead of .slice() when pushing the array.